# How to iterate across two variables per row in a macro program

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

I'm wanting to pull distinct value pairs from a table via sql and put them in a dataset, say:

```
select letters, numbers from all_values_tb
group by letters, numbers;
```

Returning say:

```
letters:    numbers:
abc         123
def         456
ghi         789
```

...then loop across those values substituting them into a macro along the lines of:

```
create table &letters._record_set as select * from connection to oracle(
    select this, that, another
    from all_values_tb 
    where numbers = &numbers.
);
quit;

data &letters._record_set;
set &letters._record_set;


ODS TAGSETS.EXCELXP STYLE = PRINTER FILE = "&letters._records.xls" OPTIONS(...);

proc print data=&letters._record_set noobs; run;

ODS TAGSETS.EXCELXP CLOSE;
```

...substituting in the values across one row of my first result set on each pass and creating a spreadsheet per pass. The script to create my spreadsheets already works fine, I just have thirty of them! One for each "letters, numbers" pair (basically, I'm obfuscating some things obviously) and I really want one script to spit them all out.

I'm completely new to SAS (only use it when I really must) and don't know enough to even google my problem very well. I get that I'm writing a macro program that needs a positional input (of some sort) but I'm not making much headway, and Oracle and SAS are the only tools I've got on this system to use. I'd love to do with python but that's not set up on our environment, and I don't think I can get the job done with PLSQL like I typically would.

Thanks in advance for any and all advice.

Comment: If you have a working program and the list of parameters in a data set try this approach. https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/Turning%20a%20program%20into%20a%20macro.md

Comment: Yeah, if I were iterating across values of one variable that would work, or I would nest two macro calls if I were sure enough of my SAS skills to keep the order of the two lists in step. But I'm trying to iterate through substituting them both in on each pass. That's what I can't seem to find a method for.

Comment: It's exactly the same, except you put two parameters in the macro definition and string.

Comment: I get that, but those would be two different lists that would have to have sequence matched between them with a large number of records and no obvious sort order that applied to both (having third column as a key only compounds my question). I'm looking to do something like indexing each column per loop and across rows between cycles in a way that maintains the link between the letters / numbers pairs.

Comment: There's nothing about that in your post. Please update your post to reflect your question.

Comment: Don't do this.  Learn more about SAS data processing, especially the BY statement and WHERE statements for sub-setting.  There are many prior questions about how an arbitray set of paired values can be grouped or linked as a relations, ie edges of a graph.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly new to SAS.

```
data &letters._record_set;
set &letters._record_set;
```

does nothing else but copy the datasets &letters._record_set over itself, so leave that out.

Let us start by defining a macro (which is similar to a precompiler routine in C++).

```
%macro print_selection(letters, numbers);
  title &letters;
  create view &letters._record_set as select * from connection to oracle(
    select this, that, another
    from all_values_tb 
    where numbers = &numbers.
  );
  quit;
  proc print data=&letters._record_set noobs; 
  run;
%mend;
```

Note that I added a title to your output and that I used views to save space in your work folder and speed up processing.

Now you should run %print_selection(letters, numbers) multiple times. You can just create the macro calls in sql `select '%print_selection('|| letters ||','|| numbers ||')'`, but to be able to execute them there are two options. `use call execute` in a datastep or use `select into ... separated by` to put them in a macro variable, which I demonstrate here:

```
select '%print_selection('|| letters ||','|| numbers ||')'
into :print_all_selections separated by '; '
from all_values_tb 
group by letters, numbers;
```

Now you have a macro variable with macro calls. You just run the calls by including that variable in your code:

```
ODS TAGSETS.EXCELXP STYLE = PRINTER FILE = "&letters._records.xls" OPTIONS(...);
&print_all_selections;
ODS TAGSETS.EXCELXP CLOSE;
```